# Fast evaluation of certain symmetric multivariate polynomials indexed by a 2-dimensional array

Tags: recursion, symmetric-polynomials

Consider a square, sparse matrix $M[a_1,a_2]:1\leq a_1,a_2\leq N$ of non-negative entries.  My question is for a given even $L>1$, how to efficiently compute the sum
$$
S:=\sum_{a!}M[a_1,a_2]\cdot M[a_3,a_4]\cdots M[a_{L-1},a_L]
$$
where sum ranges only over index vectors $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_L)$ all of whose entries are **unique**.

I'm also interested in methods to compute a part of the full sum. Here is one: Suppose we color half of the indexes $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ white, and the others black, and consider only those terms of $S$ for which each factor $M[a,b]$ has a white index for $a$ and a black index for $b$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432330/extension-of-newton-girard-to-matrix-indexed-monomials/2543696#2543696) gives an efficient recursive calculation. Apparently this trick only gets us an exponentially small proportion of the full sum.

Consider the adjacency graph, $G_M$, which is the graph with $N$ nodes having edges between $a_1$ and $a_2$ iff $M[a_1,a_2]\neq 0$. There seems to be some connection between the complexity of $S$ and the *separability* of $G_M$. For instance, the result of the previous paragraph means that $S$ can be computed efficiently if $G_M$ is bipartite.

For another example, suppose that $G$ is a union of two disconnected subgraphs $G_1,G_2$ which are connected by a single edge $E=[1,2]$ where $j\in G_j$. Let $S_j$ denote the partial sum obtained by restricting to elements of $G_j$. Then $S$ can be written as a sum of two terms, one of which contains $M[1,2]$ and the other of which doesn't; each term can be factored over the elements of $G_j$ and therefore contain significantly fewer terms than $S$. Thus, near-disconnectedness of $G$ seems to imply a substantial reduction in the complexity of computing $S$.

That's as far as I've gotten. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $M$ an adjacency matrix of a graph, this is counting matchings of order $L.$ For $L=N/2$ it is counting perfect matchings, which is [not known to have an efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Counting_problems). Your problem is basically counting weighted perfect matchings, and you can apply any of the same algorithms (see for example the discussion in [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611974331.ch113)). The sparseness doesn't help much since if you lengthen each edge by replacing it with a large odd-length path you get a graph with the same number of perfect matchings.

The method you linked to is not just the bipartite case of your problem. For example for a complete bipartite graph $K_{N/2,N/2}$ and $L=N/2,$ the restricted $S$ should be $(N/2)!$ (and the unrestricted $S$ would be $2^{N/2}(N/2)!$) but their $E_d$ would be $1.$ If you try a simple recursive approach for $S$ you'll find it takes exponential time.

Comment: Thank you! Is it true that restricting the sum to a given black/white coloring of the nodes accounts only for an exponentially-small (exponentially in $L$) proportion of the total? (I suggested in the post that a quarter of the total terms are accounted for by a given bipartite coloring; that seems to have been crazy talk.)

Comment: @MathManM: for the unrestricted sum you can orient each (white,black) pair either way, which gives a factor of $2^{L/2}.$

Comment: Also, can you comment on the complexity of the recursion given in the link?

Comment: @MathManM: it's a quadratic dynamic programming recursion, but it relies on the fact that there is a recursion into a polynomial number of subproblems (basically initial segments of the numbers)

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for the excellent paper you referenced.

Comment: I took your previous comment to mean that the dynamic programming recursion described in my other post has quadratic complexity, but how can this be since it counts all matchings of a bipartite graph? Did I misunderstand? What did you mean by 'quadratic dynamic programming'?

Comment: @MathManM: that doesn’t count all matchings - as I said it would only count one matching for $K_{d,d}.$ It only counts “non-crossing” matchings of order $d,$ by which I mean if $a_i<a_j$ then $b_i<b_j.$

Comment: Yep you're right; I see it now. Suppose we restrict the problem further to sparse *bipartite graphs where $L$ is not too large*. Does the bounded treewidth approach described in your references still apply? If not, what is the preferred approach?

Comment: @MathManM: with bounded treewidth you can compute the (weighted) matching polynomial, whose coefficients tell you the number of matchings of each order.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that the computing the matching polynomial coefficients is an effective technique against sparse bipartite graphs for small $L$? Do sparse bipartite graphs have small treewidth?

Comment: @MathManM: I was just mentioning that there are algorithms for the matching polynomial of bounded treewidth graphs. If you have any further questions please ask them as stackexchange questions.